# JavaScript: Window EventListener not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, window, dom-events, addeventlistener

I add the following event listener to the `window` object:

```
window.addEventListener( 'popstate beforeunload', () => {
    console.log('test');
});
```

I'd expect that a console log entry is being created whenever I navigate the browsers history or reload the page. However, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't add two listeners at once like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want two event listeners, you need to add them separately.

```
var handler = () => {
  console.log('test');
};
window.addEventListener('popstate', handler);
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handler);
```

Some libraries like jQuery's `.on` will automatically split on whitespace to allow this kind of thing, but `.addEventListener` itself does not.